# matplotlib is not worked with qgis

Tags: python, matplotlib, qgis

I build python plugin for qgis n i wanna use matplotlib to plot graph but while importing

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

and i got error

```
import error no module name backend_qt4agg
```

please help me to solve this. 
I have used qgis 2.8 and python 2.7.5 and centos

i have used Pip to install matplotlib

I have also used another library pygal but i got importerror 
       no moduel name pygal even though it installed properly an works fine with command prompt but not in application

Comment: It looks like the qt4 backend wasn't built for matplotlib. (It won't be by default.)  How did you install it?  Some distributions have separate backend packages for the separate backends (I'm not sure about CentOS).  If you built matplotlib from source, you'll need to make sure you have the underlying qt-dev packages installed to build the qt4agg backend.

Comment: i have used pip install matplotlib

Comment: In that case, it means matplotlib couldn't find the dependencies for the qt4 backend.  (Other backends will have been built, but QGIS needs the qt4 backend.)  Try installing `qt-devel` in your package manager.

Comment: is there any path issue i have installed pyqt4 already

Comment: qt-devel alredy installed

Comment: In that case have a look at why the qt backend isn't building.  In this case, it's best to set things up so that not building the qt backend will result in an error. Download the matplotlib source, copy the `setup.cfg.template` to `setup.cfg`, then modify the line `#qt4agg = auto` to `qt4agg = True` (note the lack of a `#` in the modified line).  Then run python `setup.py build` and have a look at the output.

Comment: It still not working

Comment: please help still i am not getting any ans.

Comment: What errors did the build give?

Comment: It was install properly but the problem did not solve it still required backed_qt4agg